# Converting map projection from OGP XML to WKT

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I need to use this map projection but epsg.io only offers the definition in OGP XML. I'll need it in WKT to load into QGIS.

Does anyone know how to convert it?

https://epsg.io/19872

Comment: It looks like the same as EPSG:3168 in QGIS.